# How do I run a function with a parameter every 5 seconds in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstimer

I want to execute the following function every 5 seconds. I have seen the other answers to related questions that say to use `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` but that only works for functions without any arguments.

The function:

```
func sayHello(name: String) {
    println("Hey \(name)!")
}
```

This is the code I tried:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello(\(name))"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But it crashes the app with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[Jake.SwiftApp sayHello(jake)]: unrecognized
selector sent to instance 0x7fcd515640a0'
```

How do I run the function with the one input parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can have your function take the `NSTimer` as an argument, which then allows you to send your data in the `userInfo` like so.

```
var timer : NSTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello:"), userInfo: "Jake", repeats: true)

func sayHello(timer: NSTimer) {
     println(timer.userInfo)
}
```

I haven't been able to test this so the timer might be malformed, but I think the logic is right.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The name parameter will change based on a series of functions that come before it. I've simplified my code to make it clearer. Do I just replace userInfo: "jake" with userInfo: name, name being a string variable?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you set up the selector for the `NSTimer` to fire, you have to pass just the name of the method.

Right now, you're dynamically building a string and trying to point to a method called:

```swift
"sayHello(jake)"
```

Which doesn't exist.  In fact, in can't exist.  This doesn't even make sense.

The `sayHello()` fun would look like this if you're adding it as a selector with a string:

```swift
"sayHello:"
```

But just fixing this will still be problems.  An `NSTimer`'s target can take zero or one arguments.  And if it does take an argument, it expects that argument to be an `NSTimer`.  When `NSTimer`'s fire and call their target, they pass themselves as a parameter.

So, we need to setup our method like this:

```swift
func sayHello(timer: NSTimer) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And now we pass `Selector("sayHello:")` for our selector argument.

In order to pass any sort of arguments in, we have to package them into the [`NSTimer`'s `userInfo` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTimer/userInfo), which is of type `AnyObject?`.  Then, within the method our timer calls, we can access this property.

```swift
class ExampleClass {
    var timer: NSTimer?

    var userName: String? {
        set {
            self.timer?.userInfo = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self.timer?.userInfo as? String
        }
    }

    func timerTick(timer: NSTimer) {
        if let userName = timer.userInfo as? String {
            self.sayHello(userName)
        }
    }

    func sayHello(userName: String) {
        println("Hello " + userName + "!")
    }

    func startTimer(#interval: NSTimeInterval = 5.0, userName: String? = nil) {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, 
            target: self, 
            selector: Selector("timerTick:"), 
            userInfo: userName, 
            repeats: true
        )
    }
}
```

From here, any time you want to change the name the timer is carrying around, you can just do:

```swift
self.userName = "Jake"
```

Comment: Which function do you call to start the timer?

Comment: `startTimer()` and you can pass it the user name to start with.

Comment: how to call timer first time immediate and after that each 5 sec