# "Ambiguous reference to member 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( _:invocation:repeats:)'"

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to set up a timer to run an event periodically, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927488/how-do-i-run-a-function-with-a-parameter-every-5-seconds-in-swift). I get that the hashtag parameter has been deprecated, so I tried to rewrite the startTimer code accordingly:

```
func startTimer()
{
    let theInterval: NSTimeInterval = 5.0
    
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval
    (
        interval: theInterval,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("timerTick:"),
        userInfo: "Hello!",
        repeats: true
    )
}
```

Problem is, I keep getting the error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( _:invocation:repeats:)'". But I'm not trying to run scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( _:invocation:repeats:), I'm trying to run scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats. I'd think that would be obvious from the parameters I'm passing.

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: you don't use the interval parameter name,  that is probably confusing the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. It is confused by the newline and whitespace between `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and the open parentheses.
2. You should not supply the first parameter label.

So, you could do:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    2.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(timerTick(_:)),
    userInfo: "Hello!",
    repeats: true
)
```

Note, I also replaced the `Selector("timerTick:")` with the `#selector` syntax.

Comment: You can also omit the class name if the selector refers to a method in the same class: `#selector(timerTick(_:))`

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Updated answer.